# Getting generic parameter from supertype class

Tags: java, reflection

Say I have a parent interface/class like so

```
interface Parent<T> {}
```

And a number of implementing interfaces that fix the generic type.

```
interface Child extends Parent<Type> {}
```

Can I use reflection to get the instance of `Class` representing `T` if I have the `Class` object for `Child`. Something like this:

```
<T, I extends Parent<T>> I create(Class<I> type) {
    Class<T> tType = ...
    ...
}
```

Currently I'm having `tType` be passed in as a parameter, but I'd like to simplify things if I can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, despite what the others have said, this info **is** available if you have access to the subclass' `Class` object.  You need to use `getGenericSuperclass` along with `getActualTypeArguments`.

```
ParameterizedType superClass = (ParameterizedType)childClass.getGenericSuperclass();
System.out.println(superClass.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
```

In your example, the "actual" type argument should return the `Class` for `Type`.

Comment: This works for a direct parent type, but not any ancestor type. It would be nice if there was a built-in method, for any `T object` and `Class<? super T> ancestorType`, to get `object`'s type parameters for `ancestorType`.

Comment: @Daniel, yes, but using a bit of recusion, you should be able to derive whichever type argument you want from any particular base class.  You should be able to create a method that allows you to specify the unreified generic `Class` and the index of the type argument (for that generic class), and obtain the `Class` for that type argument from any subclass.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do anything non-trivial with generic types at runtime, consider Guava's `TypeToken`.  It can answer your question (and many more!) while addressing some of the nuanced concerns raised by commenters:

```
private interface Parent<T> {}
private interface Intermediate<U, V> extends Parent<V> {}
private interface Child<Z> extends Comparable<Double>, Intermediate<Z, Iterable<String>> {}

public void exploreGuavaTypeTokens() {
    final TypeToken<? super Child> token = TypeToken.of(Child.class).getSupertype(Parent.class);
    final TypeToken<?> resolved = token.resolveType(Parent.class.getTypeParameters()[0]);
    System.out.println(resolved); // "java.lang.Iterable<java.lang.String>"
    final Class<?> raw = resolved.getRawType();
    System.out.println(raw); // "interface java.lang.Iterable"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't think so.  Read about [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):  the generic types are used only for compile-time checking, and then discarded.  They're not stored in the compiled class files so they're not available at runtime.

Comment: I was hoping that as they're fixed in the child type's declaration that it would be accessible.

Comment: Nope.  At runtime it's effectively just `interface Child extends Parent`.  I think the only generics information that's preserved in the compiled class is the names of the type parameters — for example, you could get the string "T" through reflection on the `Parent` interface.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The info is stored in the *class* file, it's just not available within the runtime processing of the method.  See [the relevant javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html).

Comment: The compile-time checking uses class files, you know (how else could you compile something without the entire source of the JDK?)